# Is it appropriate to have variant types as object properties in REST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, swagger, variant

In my scenario I find myself creating a REST resource representing Tasks to be run by a workflow engine.  I've created the following resource:

```
[POST|GET] /api/tasks
```

Task has the following form:

```
{
  "Id": 123456789,
  "Web": "https://foo/webfe/tasks/123456789",
  "Description": {
    "Scenario": "TaskA",
    "Parameters": {
      "GlobalParameter": "SomeCommonThing",
      "TaskASpecificParameter1": "SomeThingOnlyMeaningfulForTaskA",
      "TaskASpecificParameter2": "SomeOtherThingOnlyMeaningfulForTaskA"
    }
  }
}
```

Of note, I've got **?.Description.Parameters[]**

This Parameters field is in essence a Key-Value dictionary, but is logically schematized in a way that is directly related to the value of ?.Description.Scenario.

Is this something that makes sense in REST or is it sorta a bad idea.  Would this make more sense as a linked resource?  What about a sub-resource?

---

Bonus Questions:

How do I do this in C#/ASP.NET with Swagger/Swashbuckle in a way that is discoverable for the clients?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to visualize it as you would create it for a Database Schema. In your Tasks table, you wouldn't have a list of parameters as a potentially limitless number of columns. You would have two tables, one for Tasks and one for Parameters, and you would have a foreign key from Parameters to Task (many to one). In the same way, you would have an API endpoint that `api/Parameters` that accepts a TaskId and gives you the relevant parameters.

Following that, you could easily implement it in the API via `/api/Tasks/{TaskId}/Parameters`, or `/api/Parameters?TaskId={TaskId}`, where `/api/Parameters/{ParameterId}` returns a single parameter.

Comment: This seems unusual as well though. What would the schema say the model for parameters looks like? What about the post? Would you post to parameters and then post to tasks with a link?

Comment: It isn't very unusual; in fact I would argue it's more common to separate sources of data with their keys than to include all data by default. Like when I load up Stackoverflow/Questions, I don't want to get a list of Questions *and* all their responses and comments -- just the question title and blurb.

Comment: [Here's how Hangfire.io handles a similar situation](https://shifty.site/KsC7h). There's a jobqueue table, a job table, and a jobparameter table. Each queue has multiple jobs, each job has multiple parameters.

Comment: sure. but that's a traditional relational database, which is not the same as a REST api.  APIs are the synthesis of state as relevant to the intent of the user, whereas the database is an implementation detail.

Comment: Right, which is why I included SOverflow as an example. Slack, too, will get you a list of Channels, which you can find its messages by passing the ChannelId. Point being that it isn't atypical to separate a collection subproperty and add a reference via a key. If you want to argue about the presentation of data being relevant to the interest of the users -- well, sure, I'd never recommend designing against its use-case, but we weren't really given one.

Comment: So how would a post look in this scenario?  Would they post params to one rp and then the linked task to another?

Comment: I edited my post with two different methods. The first is the recommended method for POSTing _new_ data. With this method you've already identified the parent object from its UID, and the payload contains information solely on parameters. With this method you only need to make one request, as the request **path** contains the TaskId, and the request **body** contains the new parameters.

Comment: This still doesn't help me figure out how to expose the appropriate schema to users :/  Does it make more sense to do this by task type? that seems like it would get noisy:

[POST] api/tasks/TaskA

this would create a new TaskA with the parameters specified, but if I provided a lot of Task resource providers, this could get very messy.

Comment: It's supposed to be irrelevant which kind of task you provide. All of your tasks should be a Task object which you can POST to `api/Tasks`.